# Updating Discord Bot Nickname

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I have exhausted a lot of options and attempts at this for the last week or two. I have everything setup right but I am struggling to target the bot's Nickname.

**Desired Outcome**: I want to update the Discord Bot Nickname (not the username) ever X seconds (in this case 10) to sync with the Binance ticker price.

**Issue**: targeting the Nickname of the bot properly without issuing a command. I am getting an error that 'me' is undefined

**Code**:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
 setInterval(() => {
   client.guilds.cache.find(guild => guild.id === 'GUILD_ID').me.setNickname("$" + '${ticker.DOGEUSDT}');
 }, 10000);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
 setInterval(() => {
   client.guilds.cache.get("652865271089856525").members.cache.find(member => member.id === client.user.id).setNickname("$" + `${value}`);
 }, 10000);
})
```

For me this works absolutely well. Make sure that you are using discord.js v12, by typing `npm i discord.js@latest` in your terminal.

But I got a little hint for you: If you want to place variables inside a string you have to use ` instead of ' or ".

Comment: I actually just forgot to remove it from a previous attempt and I also am using that inside the desktop (it's bound to my Tartarus as I'm using a 60% without that symbol on the board).

Comment: @JamesHobday I've edited the code of my answer. Try this now.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Still running into the 'me' being undefined.

Comment: I was excited for a bit but it's giving me an property "members" is undefined *slams head on desk*

Comment: @JamesHobday you are using discord.js v12 right?

Comment: Correct. It entirely could be possible I'm missing something I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227131/discussion-between-james-hobday-and-jannik-schmidtke).